# Electron spiraling into nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Any idea why it is said that, if electron is a particle it'll spiral into the nucleus and disintegrate in 10^-14 seconds?

https://youtu.be/2wF_CVuWyEg?t=123 to https://youtu.be/2wF_CVuWyEg?t=142

Comment: Accelerating charges radiate energy. If an electron was a classical point charge orbiting a nucleus at the right energy, it would be under pretty extreme acceleration. Hence, it would quickly lose its energy to radiation and spiral into the nucleus.

Comment: Why did you comment what is an answer, @probably_someone?

Comment: @Quantumness Because I didn't explain where the $10^{-14}$ s comes from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per @probably_someone's answer, if electrons are point charge particles, they radiate energy when they are accelerated. If an electron orbit's a nucleus, the energy radiated per unit of time is given by [larmor's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula):

$$P=\frac{2}{3}\frac{e^2a^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^3}$$

For a single electron orbiting a nucleus of charge $Z$, the acceleration is given by Newton's formula:
$$ma = m\frac{v^2}{r}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Ze^2}{r^2}$$
$$\rightarrow v=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Ze^2}{mr}}$$

where $r$ is the distance between the electron and the nucleus.
Knowing that $P=-\frac{dE}{dt}$ where $E$ is the electron's total energy. Using the above formula we get:

$$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Ze^2}{r}=-\frac{1}{8\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Ze^2}{r}$$

Thus,

$$P=-\frac{dE}{dt}=-\frac{1}{8\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Ze^2}{r^2}\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{e^2a^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^3}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^3}\left(\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0
}\frac{Ze^2}{mr^2}\right)^2$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{dr}{dt}=-\frac{Ze^4}{12c^3\pi^2\epsilon_0^2m^2r^2}$$

Supposing that the electron start at the bohr radius $r_0$ for an atom of charge $Z$, $r_0=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}{mZe^2}$ and integrating the differential equation, we get the time $t$ when the electron "crashes" into the nucleus:

$$t=\int_0^tdt' = \int_{r_0}^0-\frac{12c^3\pi^2\epsilon_0^2m^2r^2}{Ze^4}dr=\frac{4c^3\pi^2\epsilon_0^2m^2r_0^3}{Ze^4}\sim 10^{-11}s$$

(for $Z=1$) which is very quick!

Comment: This is exactly the calculation I was getting at, but didn't have the time to do today. Thanks! It's interesting that your result is 3 orders of magnitude longer than the answer given in the video. What value are you plugging in for $Z$?

Comment: for $10^{-11}$ seconds I used $Z=1$.