# Calculating how long would an atom live if Rutherford's model were correct

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, atoms

How to calculate the time it would take for a hydrogen atom to collapse if Rutherford's model were correct? I tried using the relation between power (Larmor formula) and energy but I can't seem to get the right answer. I'm new on this site so I apologize if it's not a good question.

Comment: Could you add your calculations to the question?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527541/isnt-the-standard-proof-of-a-classical-electrons-orbit-invalid/527561